# Why is msys2 ~/.ssh folder is not used?

Tags: ssh, msys2

I have changed MSYS2 home folder to point to Windows home folder by

```
cd c:\msys64
mklink /j home c:\Users
```

And have set set `%HOME%` Windows user variable to `c:\msys64\home\<user>`

And have put `db_home: windows` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

But SSH is not reading the config folder `~/.ssh`, instead it reads `//idccmode-corp/u_drives/gowtham/.ssh`

How to make SSH read `~/.ssh`?